# Compare 2 multi dimension array and update old array to latest value in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, compare

I need your help in PHP
I have 2 array.
$old array have 5000 records
example:

```
$old = Array
 (
    'branch' => Array
        (

            '1' => Array
                (
                    'slug' => 'script',
                    'version' => '1.0.0',
                   'link' => 'oldfile'
                ),

            '2' => Array
                (
                    'slug' => 'pos',
                    'version' => '2.4.0',
                    'link' => 'oldfile'
                ),

            '3' => Array
                (
                    'slug' => 'stock',
                    'version' => '5.0.0',
                    'link' => 'oldfile'
                 
                ),

            '4' => Array
                (
                    'slug' => 'sale',
                    'version' => '22.0.2',
                    'link' => 'oldfile'
                    
                ),
        )
);
```

New Array not much maybe 10-30 records

```
$new = Array
(
    'branch' =>  Array  
         (

            '1' => Array
                (
                    'slug' => 'script',
                    'version' => '1.23.0',
                   'link' => 'newfile'
                ),

            '2' => Array
                (
                    'slug' => 'stock',
                    'version' => '5.9.0',
                    'link' => 'newfile'
                 
                ),
     )
);
```

I want to compare version from old array with new array
and want to update data in old array by change to new version and link
Example new array have new version available and new download link.

I need function that get this result

```
$old = Array
 (
    'branch' => Array
        (

            '1' => Array
                (
                    'slug' => 'script',
                    'version' => '1.23.0',
                   'link' => 'newfile'
                ),

            '2' => Array
                (
                    'slug' => 'pos',
                    'version' => '2.4.0',
                    'link' => 'oldfile'
                ),

            '3' => Array
                (
                    'slug' => 'stock',
                    'version' => '5.9.0',
                    'link' => 'newfile'
                 
                ),

            '4' => Array
                (
                    'slug' => 'sale',
                    'version' => '22.0.2',
                    'link' => 'oldfile'
                    
                ),
        )
);
```

i'm using

```
$result = array_replace_recursive($old, $new);
```

but it will replace all to old file

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While we're glad to help when you're stuck, you're still expected to make an effort of your own to reach the solution. If you have written something, please edit your question to show your code and explain where and how exactly it fails to do what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple array_replace could have solved the issue if you kept a consistent indexing when you create a new array

So my solution here finds common slug between the old and new, then remove them from the old before replacing.The assumption is that the 'slug' keys are always present and labelled the same also new array cannot be empty.Hence no checking present.

```
foreach($new['branch'] as $arrwithin){ //get arrays within the new multidim array

 foreach($old['branch'] as $key => $value){
    
  if($value['slug'] == $arrwithin['slug']){ //check if the same slugs in new array are present in the old array 

            $del[] = $key; //Get index of the old arrays within multidim where similar slugs are found as a new array

                                           }  
      } 

}

$oldclean = array_diff_key($old['branch'], array_flip($del)); //Remove the arrays which contain old slugs that have been updated in new array
$final['branch'] = array_merge($new['branch'],$oldclean); //Merge old cleaned up array with new array since well unwanted slugs are already removed

echo "<pre>";
print_r($final); //New multidim array with updated arrays 
echo "</pre>";
```

Works on PHP 5.1 and above(Tested on PHP 8)